# Stored procedure & union

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, union

I'm creating a stored procedure for data validation that is pretty straight forward.  I have several sql statements that i wish to run and simply display the results to compare to the source.  I combined the sql statements with a union but you can not union together columns of different data types.  Hopefully someone will have a suggestion on a better way to proceed?

```
USE [employee_data]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[data_employee]

AS
BEGIN

declare @LtYear as varchar(10)
set @LtYear = '2012'

SELECT 'Sum of total salary for ' + @LtYear as title, sum([Total_Salary]) as Salary
From [employee_data].[dbo].[employee]
where year = @LtYear

UNION
select 'Overall Average Salary ' + @LatestYear as title, avg([Total_Salary]) as     'Average Salary'
From [employee_data].[dbo].[employee]
where year = @LtYear

SELECT 'Employee Name - 1' as title, first_name+' '+last_name 
From [employee_data].[dbo].[employee]
where year = 2012 --@LtYear
and [First_Name] = 'first'
and [Last_Name] = 'last'

UNION
SELECT 'Individual Employee Experience ' + @LtYear as title, cast([work_Exp]as varchar) as 'Work Experience'
From [employee_data].[dbo].[employee]
where year = @LtYear
and [First_Name] = 'first'
and [Last_Name] = 'last'
```

I would like to see the results as follows:

Sum of Total Salary: 50000000
Overall Average Salary: 37000
Employee Name - 1: First Last
Individual Employee Experience 2012: 12

Comment: Casting all results to `varchar` should work for you.

Comment: Why do you need this in separate rows instead of a single row with multiple columns? Also [please don't cast as `varchar` - specify the length as well](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: copying results to a validation spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do this flipped sideways so that you don't have to use unions, you just have to scan the data sideways:

```
SELECT [Year] = @LtYear,
  [Sum of Total Salary] = s.s, 
  [Average Salary] = s.a,
  [Employee Name] = e.first_name + ' ' + e.last_name,
  [Work Experience] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), e.work_Exp
FROM employee_data.dbo.employee AS e
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT SUM(Total_Salary), AVG(Total_Salary)
  FROM employee_data.dbo.employee
  WHERE [Year] = @LtYear
) AS s(s,a)
WHERE e.[Year] = @LtYear
AND e.First_Name = @first_name
AND e.Last_Name = @last_name;
```

Not sure if you really meant to hard-code `'first'` and `'last'` but I suspect those would be better as parameters, especially if you're going to reference them multiple times.

Given that your requirements are driven by Excel, maybe try:

```
DECLARE @y CHAR(4);
SET @y = CONVERT(CHAR(4), @LtYear);

SELECT col1 = 'Sum of total salary for ' + @y, 
  col2 = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), sum(Total_Salary) as Salary)
  From employee_data.dbo.employee
  where [year] = @LtYear
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Overall Average Salary ' + @y, 
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), avg(Total_Salary))
  From employee_data.dbo.employee
  where [year] = @LtYear
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Employee Name - 1', 
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), first_name+' '+last_name)
  From employee_data.dbo.employee
  where [year] = @LtYear
  and First_Name = 'first'
  and Last_Name = 'last'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Individual Employee Experience ' + @y, 
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), work_Exp)
  From employee_data.dbo.employee
  where [year] = @LtYear
  and First_Name = 'first'
  and Last_Name = 'last';
```

Notice a few changes:

- dropped all of the aliases - they're ignored after the first statement in the union anyway.
- used explicit converts against the second column to a hopefully compatible data type.
- properly enclosed all keywords (e.g. `year`) in square brackets. Removed those that aren't necessary - they only serve to make the query harder to read.
- created a string version of the year parameter so that it could be appended to the first column without having to perform any conversion.

Now, you've dumbed down the question, and there are more queries that we can't see. But I still think a better approach would be to ditch the unions against the base table and perform it this way instead (especially if you have 10 or 15 more queries against the same table). This isn't necessarily going to perform any differently, but it will be a *lot* easier to maintain.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT 
    y = CONVERT(CHAR(4), @LtYear),
    [ss] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), s.s), 
    [as] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), s.a),
    [en] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), e.first_name + ' ' + e.last_name),
    [we] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), e.work_Exp)
  FROM employee_data.dbo.employee AS e
  CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT SUM(Total_Salary), AVG(Total_Salary)
    FROM employee_data.dbo.employee
    WHERE [Year] = @LtYear
  ) AS s(s,a)
  WHERE e.[Year] = @LtYear
  AND e.First_Name = @first_name
  AND e.Last_Name = @last_name
)
SELECT 'Sum of total salary for ' + y, [ss] FROM x
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Overall average salary for ' + y, [as] FROM x
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Employee Name - 1', [en] FROM x
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Individual Employee Experience ' + y, [we] FROM x;
```

Further to that, I think your approach is very troublesome in the first place. You're really performing data validation by cobbling these queries together and manually pasting the results into Excel? Surely there is a more automated way to do this, and instead of trying to tailor an unwieldy SQL query to conform to your process, you should improve the process...

Comment: I preferred to use separate queries and unions to make it easier to copy the results into a validation document in excel.  There are several more of these select statements.